# Ubuntu 18.10 updates fail

Tags: ubuntu, end-of-life

I have a website actually hosted on an Ubuntu 18.10 and I can't install anything. At first everything was working (a few weeks ago when I fist spawned this VPS) but now I always get error

```
me@cdad:/etc/php/7.2/mods-available$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
...
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/universe amd64 php7.2-mbstring amd64 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.10.1
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/universe amd64 php7.2-mbstring amd64 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.2/php7.2-mbstring_7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried many things, like running `sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated` or adding `[trusted=yes]` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I also checked that I have enough space on the hard drive, and that all permission are working. I disabled `ufw` but now I'm out of solution...

Any help would be awesome, I even tried this morning a version upgrade since the system was proposing it, and it failed also.

```
New release '19.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,329 kB]
Fetched 1,331 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'eoan.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade

An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool.
```

Comment: You missed the upgrade window. You will have to reinstall your server with a newer version. That's why it is always recommended to use LTS versions.

Comment: Your question is extensively discussed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Unfortunately my host installed this for me on a VPS... I didn't realized the version till I get this error... and now my whole system is installed on it... I'm screwed lol. Will try the accepted answer on the post you shared thank you !

Comment: Make sure you have backups before you do.

Comment: There's a solution to this specific problem (cosmic to eoan) here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208109/how-to-upgrade-from-18-10-to-19-10-using-the-command-line